# How to migrate from QVideoWidget to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QML application to which I want to integrate a C++ code that makes use of QMediaPlayer and QVideoWidget.

I am aware of how a media player works in QML (example from Qt):

```
Item {
    MediaPlayer {
        id: mediaplayer
        source: "groovy_video.mp4"
    }

    VideoOutput {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: mediaplayer
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: playArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: mediaplayer.play();
    }
}
```

Yet I am dealing with a code that creates QVideoWidget. I want to get rid of the QVideoWidget in the C++ side, and replace it with something I can show in my QML application.

C++ side has the following code (project in itself is quite long code, it is part of openauto project, this is the `QtVideoOutput` class that is called by C++ class `VideoService` generated by an abstract factory):

```
QtVideoOutput::QtVideoOutput(configuration::IConfiguration::Pointer configuration)
    : VideoOutput(std::move(configuration))
{
    this->moveToThread(QApplication::instance()->thread());
    connect(this, &QtVideoOutput::startPlayback, this, &QtVideoOutput::onStartPlayback, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    connect(this, &QtVideoOutput::stopPlayback, this, &QtVideoOutput::onStopPlayback, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "createVideoOutput", Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
}

void QtVideoOutput::createVideoOutput()
{
    OPENAUTO_LOG(debug) << "[QtVideoOutput] create.";
    videoWidget_ = std::make_unique<QVideoWidget>();
    mediaPlayer_ = std::make_unique<QMediaPlayer>(nullptr, QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback);
}


bool QtVideoOutput::open()
{
    return videoBuffer_.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
}

bool QtVideoOutput::init()
{
    emit startPlayback();
    return true;
}

void QtVideoOutput::stop()
{
    emit stopPlayback();
}

void QtVideoOutput::write(uint64_t, const aasdk::common::DataConstBuffer& buffer)
{
    videoBuffer_.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer.cdata), buffer.size);
}

void QtVideoOutput::onStartPlayback()
{
    videoWidget_->setAspectRatioMode(Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
    videoWidget_->setFocus();
    //videoWidget_->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
    videoWidget_->setFullScreen(true);
    videoWidget_->show();

    mediaPlayer_->setVideoOutput(videoWidget_.get()); // ???
    mediaPlayer_->setMedia(QMediaContent(), &videoBuffer_);
    mediaPlayer_->play();
    OPENAUTO_LOG(debug) << "Player error state -> " << mediaPlayer_->errorString().toStdString();
}

void QtVideoOutput::onStopPlayback()
{
    videoWidget_->hide();
    mediaPlayer_->stop();
}
```

Full code is available at: https://github.com/matt2005/openauto

My initial plan is to create a QQuick object in global context and pass it to QML. But I don't know how to do that exactly. I would like your thoughts on how to get rid of the videoWidget in the C++ side and make it use the VideoOutput / AbstractSurface that I might have on the QML side:

```
VideoOutput {
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter;
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter;
    width: 640
    height: 480
    source: ???
    objectName: "vidout"
}
```

I am willing to deliver any additional code or information as you require.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where/how you are getting the video texture data. (from the looks of it, it seems to be your `videoBuffer_`)

You can simply create a `VideoBufferVisualizer` class based on `QQuickPaintedItem` to paint the buffer data to a QtQuickItem in it's `paint(QPainter *painter)` method. Tutorial: tutorial: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-customitems-painteditem-example.html

Do note that on embedded systems there are usually faster, zero-copy, ways to get video texture data directly into an OpenGL Texture/Qt Quick Scenegraph. You can look at https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/blob/master/ext/qt/gstqtsink.cc for an idea of how gstreamer does it.